# Scaling image into tabel cell in itextpdf

Tags: android, itext

Below is my code to fit the image into pdf cell using itextpdf.Here I attched the output in which the width is smaller.I need to fit in the cell.[image: Output]

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        driverbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        image.scaleToFit(300, 39);
        cell.addElement(image);
        table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: Have you made sure that your original image does not have unnecessary empty margins?

Comment: By using scaleToFit, you are restricting the image. Comment that and check output